# Simple proof that $|xy| = |x||y|$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

<sup>Apologies if this is a duplicate, I had no luck trying to find this (simple) question anywhere.</sup>

> Define $|x| = \max\{x,-x\}$. Prove that $|xy| = |x||y|$.

This result seems incredibly intuitive, and were I to be permitted to explain in a sentence why this is true I would be able to without problem. Clearly the positive (and thus larger) product will arise in both cases by definition.  However, this is a question at the end of a chapter about finite decimal expansions of real numbers, and I'm having a hard time trying to formulate any kind of actual *proof* for this. I simply can't think of a proving method to apply to something this simple.

Comment: Proof by cases is perhaps the most plain method to go about with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) With your definition of $|\cdot|$ for every $x\in \Bbb R$ we have $$|x|=\max\{x,-x\}=\max\{-x,x\}=|-x|$$

(b) Note that $-z\leq z$ for every $z\in \Bbb R$ with $z\geq 0$ and thus $|z|=z$ if $z\geq 0$.

So let $x,y\in \Bbb R$.

(c) if $x,y\geq 0$ then $$|xy| \overset{(b)}{=} xy \overset{(b)}{=} |x||y|.$$
(d) if $y\geq 0 \geq x$ then $-x\geq 0$ and $$|xy| \overset{(a)}{=} |-xy|= |(-x)y| \overset{c)}{=} |-x||y|\overset{(a)}{=}|x||y|. $$ 
(e) if $x\geq 0 \geq y$, then $-y\geq 0 \geq -x$ and
$$|xy|=|(-x)(-y)|\overset{(d)}{=}|-x||-y|\overset{(a)}{=} |x||y|.$$
(f) if $x,y \leq 0$, then $-x,-y \geq 0$ and
$$|xy|=|(-x)(-y)|\overset{(c)}{=}|-x||-y|\overset{(a)}{=} |x||y|.$$

Comment: Utilizing his definition for $|\cdot |$, a) is even easier.

Comment: @anakhronizein makes sense, thank you I'll edit that

Comment: For some reason I figured there was a more idiomatic way to go about it then by case, but this makes sense! Thanks to the both of you @anakhronizein

Answer (score 6):

No cases are really required:

*Lemma:* $\;\lvert x\rvert=\lvert- x\rvert$.

Obvious from your definition. Hence we can suppose $x,y\ge 0$,  in which case there is nothing to prove, really.

*Variant:* Prove first that $\;\lvert x\rvert=\sqrt{x^2}$. Then use $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\cdot\sqrt b\;$ for any $a,b\ge 0$.